# Drawing root locus diagram using Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am having some problems (or so do i think) making matlab draw a  root locus diagram of closed loop system.

I have this close loop transfer function 
$T(S) = \frac{\frac{K_p}{s(s+1)} + \frac{K_iS}{s(s+1)} + \frac{K_d}{s(s(s+1))}}{1+\frac{K_p}{s(s+1)} + \frac{K_iS}{s(s+1)} + \frac{K_d}{s(s(s+1))}}$

Where i want to see how the poles are affected when  K_p  , K_i or K_d is changed. 
But i am having problems writing it in write form, in which the matlab function sees those parameter as the changing one.  I am kinda suspecting that it is just mutiplying a random gain to the system.

The way i've done it is i've reset each K_i and K_d, and plotted K_p and tried to plot K_p as being one. But that is clearly the wrong way to do, or so do i think.

this is the code i've been plotting.  rlocus(tf([1 ],[1 1 1]))

My problem is basically an isolation problems. I need to isolate the denominatior such as the wanted gain  appears as an gain for the whole system.

Comment: What is your actual question? As stated, this seems more of Matlab programming question than a math one. But you don't even show how you're using Matlab, i.e., what functions you're calling and how you're representing your system. Are you using the Control toolbox? Unless you edit this, you might consider deleting it and asking at [StackOverflow/Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab).